# How do I insert into a unique key into a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, identity

I want to insert data into a table where I don't know the next unique key that I need.  I'm not sure how to format my `INSERT` query so that the value of the Key field is 1 greater than the maximum value for the key in the table.  I know this is a hack, but I'm just running a quick test against a database and need to make sure I always send over a Unique key.

Here's the SQL I have so far:

```
INSERT INTO [CMS2000].[dbo].[aDataTypesTest]
           ([KeyFld]
           ,[Int1])
     VALUES
           ((SELECT Max([KeyFld]) FROM [dbo].[aDataTypesTest]) + 1
           ,1)
```

which errors out with:

> Msg 1046, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>   Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed.

I'm not able to modify the underlying database table.  What do I need to do to ensure a unique insert in my `INSERT` SQL code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the other INSERT syntax:

```
INSERT INTO [CMS2000].[dbo].[aDataTypesTest] 
       ([KeyFld] 
       ,[Int1]) 
SELECT Max([KeyFld]) + 1, 1 FROM [dbo].[aDataTypesTest]
```

Sorry you can't modify the database. You're right; this is a hack.

Comment: what will happen if a record has been removed in the middle?

Comment: @silent_warrior: Nothing. That deleted ID will remain unused. The same thing happens when you delete a row from the middle of a table with an IDENTITY column.

Answer (score 3):

```
INSERT INTO [CMS2000].[dbo].[aDataTypesTest]
           ([KeyFld]
           ,[Int1])
SELECT Max([KeyFld]) + 1, 1 FROM [dbo].[aDataTypesTest]
```

<strike>But why not use an IDENTITY property on KeyFld and then either SCOPE_IDENTITY() or an OUTPUT clause?</strike> (OK, no schema changes. Bummer)